# How to display phone number and pincode separately in email body using PHP-Mailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Email body displaying with **text,numbers,pincode**. I want to separate my phone number and pincode to **display in bottom of email body**. I tried `line breaks` and `<br>` no luck.

[image: Email body]

**Php code :**

```
  <?php
  $msg = "";
  $mail->Body = $body . $phone;
  $mail->Body = $pincode;
  $mail->Body = $phone;


  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    function sendemail($to, $from, $fromName, $body, $phone, $pincode) {
      $mail = new PHPMailer();
      $mail->setFrom($from, $fromName);
      $mail->addAddress($to);
      $mail->Subject = 'Naukriglobal.com - Email - Resume';
      $mail->Body = $body . $phone . $pincode;
      $mail->isHTML(false);

      return $mail->send();
    }

    $name = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $body = $_POST['body'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $pincode = $_POST['pincode'];



    if (sendemail('hameed.basha278@gmail.com', $email, $name, $body, $phone, $pincode)) {
        $msg = 'Email sent!';
        sendemail('hamidsince1990@gmail.com', $email, $name, $body, $phone, $pincode);
      } else
        $msg = 'Email failed!';
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Don't use the submitter's address as the from address; It's forgery and will get your messages bounced or spam filtered. Put your own address in from and theirs in a reply-to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the line that actually constructs the content of your message:

```
$mail->Body = $body . $phone . $pincode;
```

Here you are just concatenating all 3 fields with no spaces or line breaks.  You can add newlines between those fields like this:

```
$mail->Body = $body . "\n" . $phone . "\n" . $pincode;
```

Your `<br>`s did not work because you are sending a plain text message (you have specified `$mail->isHTML(false);`).  If you want to use HTML and `<br>`, first set `isHTML(true)`, but do that *before* you set the body:

```
function sendemail($to, $from, $fromName, $body, $phone, $pincode) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->setFrom($from, $fromName);
    $mail->addAddress($to);
    $mail->Subject = 'Naukriglobal.com - Email - Resume';
    $mail->Body = $body . "<br>" . $phone . "<br>" . $pincode;
    return $mail->send();
}
```

Or even:

```
$mail->Body = $body . "<br>Phone number: " . $phone . "<br>PIN: " . $pincode;
```

BTW you should remove this code you have at the top:

```
$msg = "";
$mail->Body = $body . $phone;
$mail->Body = $pincode;
$mail->Body = $phone;
```

`$mail` does not seem to be defined at that point, and anyway you create a new instance of `$mail` inside your `sendemail()` function so whatever you set up there will have no effect.  Remove that code to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Tried `\n` and `<br>` but no luck. `isHTML(true)` showing error in next line `$mail->`.

Comment: `"\n"`, not `/n`. I am not sure what you mean about "next line"?  What is the error?

Comment: It shows Error : `Call to a member function isHTML() on a non-object`in line of `$mail->Body = $body . "<br>" . $phone . "<br>" . $pincode;`

Comment: You must have moved your `$mail->isHTML(true);` line up before `$mail = new PHPMailer();`? It needs to be after that line, but before you set `$mail->Body = ...`

Comment: `$mail = new PHPMailer();$mail->isHTML(true);$mail->Body = $body . "<br>" . $phone . "<br>" . $pincode;` !! tried too not working :'(

Comment: What does "not working" mean - some errors? What shows up in your email? To confirm - are you editing the code inside your `sendemail()` function?

Comment: Emails showing as same before even using `isHTML`. Yes editing in `sendemail()`